# Capistrano: Run whenever tasks after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, whenever

I am using `whenever/capistrano` in my deploy.rb to update crontab on deploy
All I needed to do in my deploy script was to add these lines

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
set :whenever_environment, defer {rails_env}
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

Hooks for whenever tasks are defined as follows

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance(:must_exist).load do
  before "deploy:finalize_update", "whenever:update_crontab"
  after "deploy:rollback", "whenever:update_crontab"
end
```

Now i want to run the `whenever:update_crontab` task after migrations are run. I want the hook to be like

```
after "deploy:migrate", "whenever:update_crontab"
```

How do i overwrite the whenever hook?